# Issue in Raspberry Pi running Multi Screen Java FX App. Screen goes black after some time

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi

I want to create some multi screen (scenes) Java FX GUI app for Raspberry Pi 3B with 800x480 display (Official Raspberry Pi Touch Screen of 7 Inch).
I have set GPU to 128M.

As i switch between screens in the Java FX application, GPU memory usage increases, and free memory gets smaller and smaller and display turns black at the end and i get the error saying "glGetError 0x505"

I am monitoring GPU memory with following command:

```
sudo vcdbg rloc
```

Where does the memory go? Has any body faced such issue? Please someone help me out?

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak somewhere. Have you tried running this on a computer to see if you get the same memory leakage?

Comment: @HypnicJerk Yes i have checked the same in Windows 7 PC. Facing the same problem. Tool used to check the GPU memory usage - TechPowerUP GPUZ